# Document Not Deleting findoneanddelete mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this code that is supposed to delete a document:

```
const groups = require('./groups')
const ingroups = require('./ingroups')
    const leavegroup = await ingroups.findOne({User:message.author.id})
    //Remove 1 from the member count
    if (!leavegroup) {
    return message.reply('You are not in a group and therefore you cannot leave one.')
}
    message.reply('You have now left the group and are free to go join another one.')
    ingroups.findOneandDelete({User:message.author.id})
  }
```

It returns You have now left the group and are free to go join another one but doesn't actually delete the document in the database.

How would I make it delete the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure of the logic is incorrect and also the the `findOneAndDelete` has case errors. Please use the below suggestion to make it work.

```
const groups = require('./groups')
const ingroups = require('./ingroups')
const leavegroup = await ingroups.findOne({ User: message.author.id })
if (!leavegroup) {
    return message.reply('You are not in a group and therefore you cannot leave one.')
} else {
    await ingroups.findOneAndDelete({ User: message.author.id })
    return message.reply('You have now left the group and are free to go join another one.')
}
```